# RTC Peer Connection requires duplicate handshake

Tags: javascript, webrtc

If I create one RTC Peer Connection from one client, and set the descriptions for both local and remote, in order to make the connection work, do I need also to create another RTC Peer Connection originating from the remote client back to the local client?  My application works that way. So "s1" starts the offer and "s2" sends the answer.  But it appears to me that I need a mirroring connection originating from "s2" back to "s1" to make the video connection work.   Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

A `new RTCPeerConnection()` is needed on both ends, but only one peer is the offerer and the other peer is the answerer. The offerer calls `createOffer()`, the answerer calls `createAnswer()`.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple connections?

Comment: Nothing happens until I create another connection in reverse

Comment: Multiple peer-to-peer connections are certainly possible, but unclear what the value it would add over a single connection. By connection, I assume you mean a bi-directional peer-to-peer connection. How do you create a connection in reverse? Code would help.